# Jest: Test for function passed into object fails with 'Received: serializes to the same string'

Tags: javascript, arrays, unit-testing, oop, jestjs

I have a function that takes in an array of objects and returns a new array of objects, simplified like this:

```js
const injectArray = (arr, fn) => {
  arr.map((el) => ({
    ...el,
    fn: () => fn(el),
  }));
};
```

The test for this looks like this:

```js
const mockFn = jest.fn();

describe('injectArray()', () => {
  it('returns a new array with the function injected into the objects', () => {
    expect(injectArray([{
      name: 'John Doe',
      age: 25
    }], mockFn)).toEqual([{
      name: 'John Doe',
      age: 25,
      fn: () => mockFn();
    }]);
  });
});
```

The test fails with

```
Expected: [{"name": "John Doe", age: 25, "fn": [Function mockFn]}]
Received: serializes to the same string
```

When I change the test to `toContainEqual()` I get

```
Expected value: [{"name": "John Doe", age: 25, "fn": [Function mockFn]}]
Received array: [{"name": "John Doe", age: 25, "fn": [Function mockFn]}]
```

I believe that Jest can't compare the serialized functions and is therefore failing, but how can I avoid that in this specific use case, where I need to pass a function into an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, `jestjs` can't compare the serialized functions. You could use [expect.any(constructor)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#expectanyconstructor).

E.g.

`index.ts`:

```js
const injectArray = (arr, fn) => {
  return arr.map((el) => ({
    ...el,
    fn: () => fn(el),
  }));
};

export {injectArray}
```

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import {injectArray} from './'

const mockFn = jest.fn();

describe('injectArray()', () => {
  it('returns a new array with the function injected into the objects', () => {
    expect(injectArray([{
      name: 'John Doe',
      age: 25
    }], mockFn)).toEqual([{
      name: 'John Doe',
      age: 25,
      fn: expect.any(Function)
    }]);
  });
});
```

unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/63957885/index.test.ts
  injectArray()
    ✓ returns a new array with the function injected into the objects (4ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |       80 |      100 |    66.67 |       75 |                   |
 index.ts |       80 |      100 |    66.67 |       75 |                 4 |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.249s, estimated 13s
```

Comment: @Jacob Furthermore, you need to test the anonymous function to achieve 100% test coverage